# Deleting Cookies and Cache in chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could you please confirm can I use the:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()
```

for delete the cookies in Chrome. And also please provide the statements for deleting the cache in chrome and IE. And also how confirm the cookies and cache is deleted in the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `deleteAllCookies()` will clear all cookies not **CACHE**. Currently there is not a way to clear the cache with Selenium, at last not that I know. However, I think you do not need to do that either since Selenium by default creates a new profile every time.

See this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40) which has been opened since 2010. And more detail discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310888/clear-browser-cache-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Thanks for your comments saifur.